# MongoDB Morphia only saving 1 user

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

Hi guys i'me having troubles using morphia for mongodb this is what im creating.
Im creating a spigot plugin for my hub server and im using mongodb with morphia for store my user object to my collection and this object only store 1 user instead of saving all users into the collection.

My user object

```
@Entity(value = "clientdata", noClassnameStored = true)
public class ClientData {

@Id
public int id;

@Indexed(options = @IndexOptions(unique = true))
private String uuid;

@Indexed
private String lastName, username, lastLoginDate, ip;

@Indexed
private int level, exp, joins, coins, pearls;

@Property("hats")
private List<Integer> hatsOwned;

public ClientData(){
    this.hatsOwned = new ArrayList<>();

    if(this.hatsOwned.isEmpty()){
        this.hatsOwned.add(0);
    }
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getIp() {
    return ip;
}

public void setIp(String ip) {
    this.ip = ip;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUuid() {
    return uuid;
}

public void setUuid(String uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public int getLevel() {
    return level;
}

public void setLevel(int level) {
    this.level = level;
}

public int getExp() {
    return exp;
}

public void setExp(int exp) {
    this.exp = exp;
}

public int getJoins() {
    return joins;
}

public void setJoins(int joins) {
    this.joins = joins;
}

public void addJoins(int joins) {
    this.joins += joins;
}

public int getCoins() {
    return coins;
}

public void setCoins(int coins) {
    this.coins = coins;
}

public int getPearls() {
    return pearls;
}

public void setPearls(int pearls) {
    this.pearls = pearls;
}

public List<Integer> getHatsOwned() {
    return hatsOwned;
}

public void setHatsOwned(List<Integer> hatsOwned) {
    this.hatsOwned = hatsOwned;
}

public void addNewHatOwned(int hatID){
    this.hatsOwned.add(hatID);
}

public String getLastLoginDate() {
    return lastLoginDate;
}

public void setLastLoginDate(String lastLoginDate) {
    this.lastLoginDate = lastLoginDate;
}
}
```

My mongo manager class

```
public class MongoManager {
private static MongoManager ins = new MongoManager();

private MongoClient mc;
private Morphia morphia;
private Datastore datastore;
private ClientDAO userDAO;

public static MongoManager get() {
    return ins;
}

public void init() {
    ServerAddress addr = new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017);
    List<MongoCredential> credentials = new ArrayList<>();
    credentials.add(MongoCredential.createCredential("union", "admin", "union16".toCharArray()));
    mc = new MongoClient(addr, credentials);

    morphia = new Morphia();

    morphia.map(ClientData.class);

    datastore = morphia.createDatastore(mc, "admin");
    datastore.ensureIndexes();

    userDAO = new ClientDAO(ClientData.class, datastore);
}

public void disconnect(){
    this.mc.close();
}

public ClientData getUserByPlayer(Player player) {
    ClientData du = userDAO.findOne("uuid", player.getUniqueId().toString());
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (du == null) {
        du = new ClientData();
        du.setUuid(player.getUniqueId().toString());
        du.setCoins(0);
        du.setExp(0);
        du.setJoins(0);
        du.setLastLoginDate(DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(time));
        du.setLevel(0);
        du.setPearls(0);
        du.setIp(player.getAddress().getAddress().toString());
        du.setUsername(player.getDisplayName());
        du.setLastName(player.getName());
        du.setHatsOwned(null);
        userDAO.save(du);
    }
    return du;
}


public void saveUser(ClientData user) {
    userDAO.save(user);
}

public List<ClientData> getAllUsers() {
    return userDAO.find().asList();
}
}
```

Comment: We would need the code that calls getUserByPlayer, and see what the PLayers look like. as far as I can tell, the players could all have the same uniqueId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't insert more than one because you have duplicateKey: **you can't use an @id with primitive type without setting a unique value yourself**.

You defined your id like this:

```
@Id
public int id;
```

Even though you never set any value for id, primitive types are initialized to `0`, so you end up trying to insert multiple documents with the same key.

#### Solution:

You can either :

- change your `id` to **String**: `@Id String id;`
- change your `id` to **ObjectId**: `@Id ObjectId id;`
- keep `@Id int id` and manually set a unique value to it (`player.getUniqueId()` for instance).

The first 2 options will work because they won't be initialized and will be null. Mongo will then generate a unique id for you.

Comment: So i only change the variable type, the annotation stays?

Comment: Thx :D its working, just one last question, how can i add a list to my user data? ex List<Hat> hats; Property annotation is correct?